# Why do we not consider the Alexandroff extension of an affine space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have read that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is a natural compactification of $\mathbb{A}^n$ over say $\mathbb{C}.$ However, usually in topology, we like to consider the one-point-compactification of a topological space to compactify it. Is there a reason why this is not mentioned as a natural compatification of $\mathbb{A}^n$? The Alexandroff extension of an affine space is compact and connected so it seems like it has some nice properties. However, it doesn't seem Hausdorff. Is this a reason why we don't study this as one of the compactifications? Are there other reasons?

Comment: the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb A^n$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Doesn't that require $\mathbb{A}^n$ to be Hausdorff itself as a OPC of $X$ is Hausdorff iff $X$ is Hausdorff and locally compact? I thought that the complex affine $n$-space was not Hausdorff. But I have also seen that the projective one-space is Hausdorff and is the OPC of affine one-space but the affine one-space is not Hausdorff.

Comment: Oh nevermind. I think I am confusing Zariski topology and Euclidean topology. I agree that the OPC of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is Hausdorff. But the OPC of the affine space with the Zariski topology doesn't seem Hausdorff. But in any case, the OPC with Euclidean topology seems pretty good?

Comment: It is trivially identified with the $n$-sphere via the [stereographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#Applications_within_mathematics), and this is used in complex analysis to study singularities at infinity, for example. But polynomials do not extend as nicely to it as they do to the projective space.